# Custom Launcher How to insert an App on the home screen

Tags: android, xml, android-launcher

I have been spending a lot of time on the AOSP site and while I have been learning a lot about making custom roms etc, I have been having trouble understanding how an app is put on a home screen.

I decided to make my own custom Launcher and while a lot of tutorials show you how to add a button on the home screen then that button takes you to a list of apps you can launch as shown [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358), I can't find a tutorial that shows me how to put a default app like "Settings" onto the screen.

I have been reading up on the AOSP source for their default launcher [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/res/layout/) but I got even more confused >=/

I guess in short, if I have a simple layout.xml with nothing but a wallpaper, How would I have to insert in the xml and java file to put to display the settings app? Are they actually the app itself or am I only allowed to insert shortcuts?

From what I gather, I would have to get some intent info from the packageManager but other than that, I am having a hard time understanding the process